# how to write a OWL to let reasoner to do ordering and show in inferred axiom when use with InferredOntologyGenerator

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, protege

object property has distance, i do not know whether reasoner can make ordering when display inferred axioms and would like to try this way.
but meet error at decimal

there is a distance between gene A and gene B range from 0 to a decimal value
would like to display ordering of gene

if having more gene C and D, and has distance between A and C, C and D, A and D etc, with one distance property seems not enough, how to define well in this case?

**which algorithm can sort by distance of many pairs?**

is it to sort by distance first and start the minimum distance (a,b) and then second minimum distance since a is neighbor of b , c is neighbor of b , then attach c next to b

if this is so simple, why need to use sweep and prune ?

```
a 2 b 3 c

a b 2
a c 5
b c 3

a b 2
b c 3
a c 5


Gene
 and (distance some decimal[ >"0.0", <"2.0"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The OWLReasoner interface specifies Sets as output, so the order of inferred axioms is not determined by the reasoner.

For your use case, I would implement a Comparator and sort the inferred axioms after they have been created.